# Is a MSM with no lagged values equivalent to simply using IPW to balance a data set?

Tags: panel-data, causality, propensity-scores

I am working on a project employing a panel data set with a large N but a fairly small T (5 time periods). MSMs seem like a good strategy, but I am wary of the incorporation of lagged values since this will omit the first time period, which has major costs for my project given the small T.

If I do not include lagged values in either the construction of the IP weights nor the outcome model, is the resulting model simply a case of IPW that balances covariates better than regression adjustment, without necessarily accounting for the biasing properties of past treatment histories and treatment-time varying confounder feedback loops?